# Change default field properties for number format in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes

Anyone who has worked with numbers that have more than 14 digits has run into ArcMap's wonderful habit of converting any number of such length to e-notation. While changing this is a simple matter of going into the Field Properties and setting the number format, doing this repeatedly for every field in every table grows tiresome. Is there some secret environment setting or method to make number formats default to something besides "Numeric"?

Comment: Are you looking for a [programmatic solution](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/NumberFormat_Property/002500000363000000/) ?

Comment: I'm just looking for a -solution-. Chances are that an ArcObjects one is outside of my scope, however, unless it's an already-built AddIn.

Comment: @Kirk After digging in to ArcObjects a little bit in the past week, it seems that the INumberFormat interface is only useful for changing the way the field displays when you use `valuetostring` and `stringtovalue` methods. Is this the case, or will it actually adjust the way it is seen in the table in ArcMap?

Comment: Sorry, you should be able to cast it to [INumericFormat](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/INumericFormat_Interface/004200000157000000/).

Comment: This is generally a database limitation (15) and not specific to ArcGIS, putting that aside, is it a Short, Long, Double or a Float?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As best as I can tell, the answer is no, one can't set the default number format, not without programming (and for that one would start with [INumericFormat](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/INumericFormat_Interface/004200000157000000/) as noted by Kirk. See example for [Decimal Degree Angle Radian](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Decimal_Degree_Angle_Radian_Example_Snippet/004900000081000000/) and [Currency Format](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00490000005v000000)).

Also the numeric display property is stored in the map (.mxd) or layer file (.lyr) and not a property if the table itself, so any changes made interactively or via the programming like the above won't apply to new data. Changing the field numeric type at creation time to doublem, float, etc. won't help either, for the same reason (it's not a field or table property).

Presumably this means the only way forward is to hope someone builds and shares a "change numeric format for all selected layers" button in Arcmap, and/or post a feature request to http://ideas.arcgis.com and hope the powers that be decide it's worth implementing as a user preference.

Answer (score 3):

I found next solution:

`Carto.FeatureLayer` class implements `Geodatabase.ITableFields` and `Geodatabase.ILayerFields` interfaces. Via one of these two interfaces you can access `FieldInfo` property type of `Geodatabase.IFieldInfo`. Then use `IFieldInfo.NumberFormat` property.